# while statement not echoing out info

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, So I have 2 different tables in one DB, I am trying to use a while statement to echo out a name from one table and then echo out a selector for each name..

For instance, If there is only one name in the table, There would be only one selector, Else if there was two names, But the options selected value should be set to what it says in the DB... Right now everything is echoing out correctly but all the selected for the option are not being unique, They are staying the same as the one before it. So If I set one to disabled, The selector shows them all as disabled.. Here is the code

```
 <?php


            $userID = $_GET['uid']; // from the query string in the link

            $_SESSION['userid'] = $userID;

            $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = '". $userID ."'") or die(mysqli_error()); 
            $query->execute();
            $user=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // echo out user details:

            echo '<b>' . 'User Info:' . " " . '</b>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo  $user['last']. "," . " " .$user['first'];
            echo '<br>';
            echo 'Business Unit';
            echo '<br>';
            echo $user['busunit'];
            echo '<br>';
            echo 'Location';
            echo '<br>';
            echo $user['location'];
            echo '<br>';
            echo 'Position';
            echo '<br>';
            echo $user['position'];

            echo '<br>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<b>Access Info</b>';
            echo '<br>';
            $number = '1';
            $number++;

            $new = 'op' . $number;



            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM access");
            $stmt->execute();

            $userIDi = $user['ident'];
            $q = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM priv WHERE ident = :ID ");
            $q->bindparam(":ID", $userIDi);
            $q->execute();
            $priv=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $val1 = 'Yes';
            $val2 = 'No';


            echo '<form method="post">';

            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo $row['name'];
                echo ' ';
                echo '
                <select id='.$new.'>
                <option value="Yes"';  
                if($priv[$new]==$val1){echo 'selected="selected"';}   echo '>Enabled </option>';
                echo '<option value="No"';   
                if($priv[$new]==$val2){echo 'selected="selected"'; }  echo '>Disabled </option>';
                echo '</select>';
                echo '<br>';





            }
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
            echo '</form>';
```

Updated code to this,
Still cannot get it to work.

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo $row['name'];
                echo ' ';


                echo '
                <select id='.$new.'>';

                while($priv=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

                echo '<option value="Yes"'; if($priv[$new]==$val1){echo 'selected="selected"' . '>Enabled </option>';}





                echo '<option value="No"'; if($priv[$new]==$val2){echo 'selected="selected"' . '>Disabled </option>'; }
                }   




                echo '</select>';

                echo '<br>';



            }
```

Here is the third update..

Now the first selector is working dynamiclly, It will changed to enabled or disabled but the other ones just stay static.

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo $row['name'];
                echo ' ';
                echo '
                <select id='.$new.'>

                <option value="Yes"'; 

                while($priv=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

                if($priv[$new]==$val1){echo 'selected="selected"';}  echo '>Enabled </option>';

                echo '<option value="No"';  


                if($priv[$new]==$val2){echo 'selected="selected"'; }}  echo '>Disabled </option>';

                echo '</select>';

                echo '<br>';



            }
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
            echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Nothing in your `while` actually changes during the cycle, all you do is output a different `$row['name']` and the same `$priv[$new]` data over and over again. Isn't the `$priv[$new]` supposed to be specific to the fetched `$row` for each iteration in some way?

Comment: Yes, I dont know how to get it there though.. Thats why im asking this question

Comment: I have tried it like this now, still cant get it `while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
     echo $row['name'];
     echo ' ';

     
     echo '
     <select id='.$new.'>';

     while($priv=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

     echo '<option value="Yes"'; if($priv[$new]==$val1){echo 'selected="selected"' . '>Enabled </option>';}

     

       

     echo '<option value="No"'; if($priv[$new]==$val2){echo 'selected="selected"' . '>Disabled </option>'; }
     } 


     

     echo '</select>';

     echo '<br>';
     
 
     
    }`

Comment: I think you should do your `$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM access");` inside the cycle and restrict the query to your current data in `$row` then just use the first row returned.

Comment: @TonyBogdanov Updated code above

Comment: Nope, now you just walk everything from `access` once for the first iteration then 0 times for each of the next iterations. Put your entire query preparation, execution and fetching inside the cycle and restrict it to the current `$row`, the two tables should be connected in some way, no?

Comment: Could you please make an aexample for me

Comment: The bottom line thing here is I need two loops to constantly echo names from the names table and I need selector to be echoing out beside those names and setting the selected value of each option to the current one in the priv table

Comment: There are too many things I don't know about your code, but here's a pseudo-code of my idea, let me know if you get it: `foreach(person in people) { wallet = prepare_and_fetch_first_row('from wallet where wallet.owner = person'); }`

Comment: no idea what that means, I dont understand how there is too much you dont know about my code, I posted it there for you. If your going to use an example please make it from my code.

Comment: So I should run a foreach on the Priv instead of while then run the stmt for acces in that foreach?

Comment: Probably, what do you have in the `priv` table anyway and how is it related to `access`?

Comment: 1 SQL injection and 5 XSSes via `$user`...

Comment: @TonyBogdanov updated code again above, Now the first selector is working and changing based on DB value but the other selectors are staying the same.

Comment: @Przemek Not my question at all.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123: This is why my comment was a comment, not an answer. You should know about having something this ugly in your code before pushing it to the production.

Comment: @Przemek Who said this is production? Im testing.. Thats why im finding bugs and requesting help on the forums.. Also, I would love to see the SQL injection your talking about

Comment: I didn't said it is in production, I said it eventually will. SQL injection is here: http://pastebin.com/0r6WcNPn . You are not preparing query the right way and I wanted to warn you about it.